Can I instrument multiple (related) variables with a single instrumental variable?
I have a valid instrumental variable, $Z$, for my endogenous variable $DeathRate$. I can decompose the latter into components, e.g.:
$$
DeathRate = DeathRate^{GroupA} + DeathRate^{GroupB}
$$
Could I then use my single $Z$ to instrument both components?

Only if $Z$ also decomposes into $Z_A$ and $Z_B$ (and thus provides two instruments), or else your model is unidentified.
